# Regex which works only in tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript I try to match any **attributes with value** which starts with "on" (it could be *onerror*, *onmouseover*, etc.), my example:

```
/<*?(on[^=-\s]+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/gmi
```

(online example: https://www.regex101.com/r/dQ4xH4/1)

But I want to work this regular expressin only in tags (between '<' and '>' characters) So as you can see in current example the regex matches even outside of tags. How can I modify my regex that it maths only in tags (any tags)?

Comment: Is this for node.js or something? Why are you doing this with regular expressions?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Seriously, though, you can't reliably parse your HTML with any single regex.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have built a DOM of the HTML you're trying to process:

```
var nodes = root.getElementsByTagName('*');

var result = [].filter.call(nodes, function(el) {
    return [].some.call(el.attributes, function(attr) {
        return attr.name.match(/^on/i);
    });
});
```

It iterates over all elements that are found under `root` and inspects whether any of the attribute names starts with `on`.

Comment: I didn't know `'*'` was a valid parameter for `getElementsByTagName` o.O

Answer (score -1):

Do a non-greedy match for `[^>]` to make sure you are still inside the HTML element.

`<[^>]*?(on[^=-\s]+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?`

Comment: Look at what that regex matches, for this element: `<img onerror="alert(2 > 4)">`

Answer (score -1):

You can try several different solutions depending on what your actualy need:
Lets take this tag as an example :`<source onerror="alert(1)">`

1. geting only attribute name and value (matches exclude = and "):

`/<{1}\w+[\w\s\'\"\=]*(on[^=-\s]+)=["']([\S\w\d]*|[\S\w\d ]*)["']>{1}/gmi`

this will return array looking like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'onerror' 
  1 => string 'alert(1)'
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/6) with multiple tests

2. geting attribute with value (matches include = and "):

`/<{1}\w+[\w\s\'\"\=]*((on[^=-\s]+)=["']([\S\w\d]*|[\S\w\d ]*)["'])>{1}/gmi`

this will return array looking like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'onerror="alert(1)"' 
  1 => string 'onerror'
  2 => string 'alert(1)'
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/8) with multiple tests

3. geting the entire tag:

`/(<{1}\w+[\w\s\'\"\=]*(on[^=-\s]+)=["']([\S\w\d]*|[\S\w\d ]*)["']>{1})/gmi`

this will return array looking like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '<source onerror="alert(1)">' 
  1 => string 'onerror'
  2 => string 'alert(1)'
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/7) with multiple tests

4. geting all of the above:

`/(<{1}\w+[\w\s\'\"\=]*((on[^=-\s]+)=["']([\S\w\d]*|[\S\w\d ]*)["'])>{1})/gmi`

this will return array looking like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '<source onerror="alert(1)">' 
  1 => string 'onerror="alert(1)"'
  2 => string 'onerror'
  3 => string 'alert(1)'
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/9) with multiple tests

EDIT: This is my final edit of this answer. I will not continue to expand it since RegEx is a "not recomended" way to parse HTML code.

Comment: [It's not matching `<img onerror="alert(2 > 4)">`.](https://www.regex101.com/r/dQ4xH4/15)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I found [another common use-case that doesn't work with your regex.](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/1)

Comment: @Cerbrus I have updated my DEMO and code yet again tell me if it works for you.

Comment: It now matches [2 tags when they're placed after each other](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK0oF6/3).

Comment: @Cerbrus I have another update for you, check the demo and let me know if you can think of any more issues

Comment: It appears to be okay, now.

Comment: Look on the demo example and description about attributes please, it should match onerror="alert(shouldMatch)" instead of <img onerror="alert(shouldMatch)">